# Getting a 500 Internal Server Error when rewriting 2 specific URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess

I keep getting a 500 internal server error when trying to rewrite these one specific URLs/files (item.php & purchase.php), the rest works.

I have tried many ways to fix this but nothing seemed to work, which is weird because all other URLs do work, but these 2 just seem to not want to work for some reason.

**.htaccess file**

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

ErrorDocument 500 "500"
ErrorDocument 404 "404"
ErrorDocument 403 "403"


RewriteRule ^users/([^/]*)$ /user/profile.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^users/([^/]*)/inventory$ /user/GetUserInventory.php?username=$1

RewriteRule ^market/item/([^/]*)$ /market/item.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^market/item/([^/]*)/purchase$ /market/purchase.php?id=$1

RewriteRule ^community/([^/]*)$ /communities/view.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^community/([^/]*)/join$ /communities/join.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^community/([^/]*)/manage$ /communities/manage.php?id=$1

RewriteRule ^game/([^/]*)$ /games/view.php?id=$1
```

**item.php**

```php
<?php
    include_once('../private/header.php');
    $item = $handler->query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id=" . $_GET['id']);
    $gB = $item->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    echo '
    <div class="col s12 m9 l8">
    <div class="container" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="content-box" style="border-radius:0;">
    <div class="left-align">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m6 l3 center-align">
    <img src="'.$cdnServer.'/items/thumbnails/'.$gB->image.'.png" class="responsive-img">
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m6 l6">
    <div style="padding-left:25px;overflow:hidden;">
    <div style="font-size:26px;font-weight:300;">'.$gB->name.'
    <b style="text-transform:uppercase;font-size:12px;">'.$gB->type.'</b>
    </div>
    <div style="color:#777;font-size:14px;">'.$gB->description.'</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m3 l3 center-align" style="padding-top:15px;">
    <center>
    ';

    if ($gB->onsale == 1){
        echo '<a href="'.$serverUrl.'/market/item/'.$gB->id.'/purchase" class="modal-trigger waves-effect waves-light btn green">Purchase</a>';
    } else {
        echo '<a class="modal-trigger waves-effect waves-light btn grey darken-2">Offsale</a>';
    }

    echo '
    </center>
    <div style="height:15px;"></div>
    <center><b style="text-transform:uppercase">Creator</b></center>
    <center><a href="'.$serverUrl.'/users/'.$gB->creator.'" style="padding-top:12px;font-size:16px;display:inline-block;">'.$gB->creator.'</a></center>
    ';

    if($gB->collectable == 'true'){
        if($gB->amount == 0)
            echo '
            <center><span style="color:red">Sold Out</span></center>
            ';
        }else{
            echo '
            <center><span style="color:red">'.$gB->amount.' Remaining</span></center>
            ';
    }

    echo '
    <div style="height:25px;"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-top:25px;">
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:0;">
    <div class="col s12 m12 l3 center-align">
    <div style="font-size:20px;">'.$gB->created.'</div>
    <div style="color:#999;font-size:14px;">Time Created</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m12 l3 center-align">
    <div style="font-size:20px;">'.$gB->created.'</div>
    <div style="color:#999;font-size:14px;">Last Updated</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m12 l3 center-align">
    <div style="font-size:20px;">???</div>
    <div style="color:#999;font-size:14px;">Owners</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    ';

    include_once('../private/footer.php');
```

**purchase.php**

```php
<?php
    include_once('../private/config.php');

    if ($user){
        $money=$myu->CurrencyCoins;
        $id=$_GET['id'];
        $item = $handler->query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id=" . $id);
        $gB = $item->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $amount=$gB->amount;

        if ($gB->onsale == 1){
            if ($money >= $gB->price){
                if ($gB->collectable != "true"){
                    if ($amount != 0){
                        $new = ($money - $gB->price);
                        $handler->query("UPDATE `users` SET `CurrencyCoins`='".$new."' WHERE `id`='".$myu->id."'");
                        $handler->query("INSERT INTO inventory (item,user) VALUES (".$id.",".$myu->id.")");
                    }
            } else {
                if ($amount >= 1){
                    $amount1=($amount - 1);
                    $new = ($money - $gB->price);
                    $handler->query("UPDATE `users` SET `CurrencyCoins`='".$new."' WHERE `id`='".$myu->id."'");
                    $handler->query("UPDATE `items` SET `amount`='".$amount1."' WHERE `id`='".$gB->id."'");
                    $handler->query("INSERT INTO inventory (item,user) VALUES (".$id.",".$myu->id.")");
                } else {
                    echo '<center><h2>Item is sold out!</h2></center>';
                }
                }
            }
        } else {
        echo '<center><h2>Item not on sale!</h2></center>';
        }
    }

    echo '<head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url='.$serverUrl.'/account/character"></head>';
```

Comment: What is the actual URL you are requesting... both that does not work and works. Your rule that appends the `.php` extension has a potential error that could cause this, but without knowing the exact URLs, we can't be sure that is the current problem. Also, the filesystem structure... what are the physical directories and files?

Comment: Which two fail? What is the error? You are open to SQL injections with this code.

Comment: Have you confirmed the php files work by directly going to them? This may or may not have anything to do with rewrites.

Comment: @IncredibleHat Yes. The files do work.

Comment: @user3783243 item.php and purchase.php do not work, but only if going to the rewritten URL. If I go to the un-rewritten URL it works.

Comment: @MrWhite Original URL:

item.php
example.com/market/item.php?id=1
example.com/market/item/1

purchase.php
example.com/market/purchase.php?id=1
example.com/market/item/1/purchase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
> ```

These directives should be at the end of your `.htaccess` file, *after* the other rewrites. They are also incorrect - although by placing them at the end of the file it will avoid the immediate issue, but could still cause problems with other URLs.

In its current state, when you request `example.com/market/item/1` (where it would seem, `/market` is a physical directory, and `/item.php` is a file in that directory) then...

**In brief...** it results in an endless rewrite loop:

```
/market/item/1.php
/market/item/1.php.php
/market/item/1.php.php.php
/market/item/1.php.php.php.php
etc.
```

Which breaks (after 10 iterations) with a 500 response being sent to the browser.

A very similar process happens when requesting `/market/item/1/purchase`:

```
/market/item/1/purchase.php
/market/item/1/purchase.php.php
/market/item/1/purchase.php.php.php
/market/item/1/purchase.php.php.php.php
etc.
```

**In detail...**

1. `REQUEST_FILENAME` is `/market/item` (ignoring the directory-prefix) and `PATH_INFO` is `/1` (important for later). `/market/item` is not a directory (1st condition), but `/market/item.php` is a file (2nd condition) - so both conditions are successfully met.
2. The `RewriteRule` directive then rewrites `/market/item/1` to `/market/item/1.php` (clearly incorrect and not the intention). Since there is no `L` flag on this rule, processing continues... for the sake of the remaining rules, the `PATH_INFO` (from the initial request, `/1`) is appended to the resulting URL to become `/market/item/1.php/1` (the `DPI` flag - discard path info - was created to prevent this specific behaviour).
3. `/market/item/1.php/1` does not match any further rules in the current pass, so the rewrite engine starts over at the top with `/market/item/1.php`.
4. `REQUEST_FILENAME` is again `/market/item` and `PATH_INFO` is now `/1.php`. `/market/item` is not a directory (1st condition), but `/market/item.php` is a file (2nd condition) - so both conditions are successfully met a second time.
5. The `RewriteRule` directive then rewrites `/market/item/1.php` to `/market/item/1.php.php`. Since there is no `L` flag on this rule, processing continues... for the sake of the remaining rules, the `PATH_INFO` (from the request, `/1.php` this time) is appended to the resulting URL to become `/market/item/1.php.php/1.php`.
6. `/market/item/1.php.php/1.php` does not match any further rules in the current pass, so the rewrite engine starts over at the top with `/market/item/1.php.php`.
7. GOTO #4 (with updated URL-path) etc. etc. etc. rewrite loop, 500 error.

And a very similar process happens when requesting `/market/item/1/purchase`. The `REQUEST_FILENAME` is the same `/market/item` (so it again checks that `/market/item.php` exists, not `purchase.php`), except that the `PATH_INFO` is `/1/purchase` (not `/1`). And the initial URL-path that the `.php` extension is appended to is naturaly `/market/item/1/purchase` (not `/market/item/1`).

#### Fix

If you've followed that "confusing muddle", you'll see that the condition that checks for the existence of the "path/to/file" + ".php" is not necessarily the same as the rule that actually rewrites the request to "URL-path" + ".php". ("path/to/file" is not the same as the "URL-path"). To fix this, it should be written as:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f 
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

No real need for the directory check here, since if it was a directory, the file check that follows *must* fail (unless you have directory names that end in `.php`). The `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php` check is now effectively "the same" as `$1.php` (the file being rewritten to).

The literal dot does not need to be backslash escaped in the `RewriteCond` *TestString* - this is an "ordinary" string, not a regex.

Don't forget the `L` flag(s). And this rule block should now go at the end of the `.htaccess` file.

### Summary

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on 

ErrorDocument 500 "500"
ErrorDocument 404 "404"
ErrorDocument 403 "403"

RewriteRule ^users/([^/]*)$ /user/profile.php?username=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^users/([^/]*)/inventory$ /user/GetUserInventory.php?username=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^market/item/([^/]*)$ /market/item.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^market/item/([^/]*)/purchase$ /market/purchase.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^community/([^/]*)$ /communities/view.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^community/([^/]*)/join$ /communities/join.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^community/([^/]*)/manage$ /communities/manage.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^game/([^/]*)$ /games/view.php?id=$1 [L]

# Append .php on remaining requests
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f 
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Flipping those two lines might still be required, so that `purchase` will be matched first.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Reversing those two directives (and the others for that matter) would perhaps be more _logical_ (and generally safer - the most specific rule first). However, it shouldn't matter in this case due to the end pattern `([^/]*)$` on the preceding rule. If they had instead used the more general `(.*)$` - then order would matter.